# How to make an SVG self-animate

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, random, hover

My website home page http://creativespectrums.com/ contains an SVG made out of concentric circles. I would like to bring life to it.

Is it possible to make it self-animate with a random pattern? I would also like it to respond to hovering. The effect I am looking for is similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNJw4AA0Gus.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the SVG as a background image you can use CSS to animate the whole image.

You can also animate each layer differently but this will require a IMG tag for your svg and this is not supported in IE for img tag animation.

What I would recommend is to make each layer a separate background image on multiple elements then animate them all when the container is hovered over.

Hope this helps